# How do I add an article to #__content from my component?

Tags: component, development

My component needs to add articles from the front-end in a non-conventional way. I realize I can just insert them with MySQL, but I'd like to use the core functions to do so (if it's possible).

Having studied the code in components\com_content, I'm a little overwhelmed by everything that needs to happen, and was hoping that I'm just overcomplicating it.

Are there any examples of this in Joomla, or a convention of steps to be followed to accomplish it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the model file and add these lines inside the model class:

```
public function getContentTable($type = 'Content', $prefix = 'JTable', $config = array())
{
    return JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
}
```

Now you can define a method inside the model class to add an article. Something like this:

```
public function addArticle()
{
    $table = $this->getContentTable();
    $table->title = "Foo";
    $table->alias = "foo";
    // or
    // $table->alias = JApplication::stringURLSafe($table->title);
    $table->catid = 2;
    $table->state = 1;
    // and so on!
    // then save it
    $table->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had to load articles in an unconventional way. I was able to leverage a lot of the Joomla code for this. You made need to adjust this based on your needs.

This function will return an artlice given an id (numeric) or an alias.

```
    function loadArticle($id){

            $app = JFactory::getApplication();
            $db = JFactory::getDBO();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $selects = array('a.introtext','a.publish_up','a.publish_down');
            $query->select($selects);
            $query->from('#__content as a');

            // select the alias or id
            $where = 'a.title = ' . $db->q(NNText::html_entity_decoder($id));
            $where .= ' OR a.alias = ' . $db->q(NNText::html_entity_decoder($id));
            if (is_numeric($id)) {
                    $where .= ' OR a.id = ' . $id;
            }

            $query->where('(' . $where . ')');

            // check the publish and unpublish dates
            $now = JFactory::getDate('now','UTC');
            $nullDate = $db->getNullDate();

            $query->where('a.state = 1');

            $query->where('( a.publish_up = ' . $db->q($nullDate) . ' OR a.publish_up <= ' . $db->q($now) . ' )');
            $query->where('( a.publish_down = ' . $db->q($nullDate) . ' OR a.publish_down >= ' . $db->q($now) . ' )');

            $db->setQuery($query);
            $article = $db->loadObject();
            return $article;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a good clean starting point to GET an article, but I need to ADD an article...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood